# XSLT display parameter with PHP

Tags: php, xslt, coldfusion, parameters

I am passing the parameter `movieID` in the following XSLT code

```
<xsl:template match="movie">
  <xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

I want to pass and display it on the page called `movie_details.php`.

This is my movie_details.php code:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('movies.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('movie_details.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$params = $_GET['movieID'];

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml,$params);
?>
```

movie_details.xsl page contains the following parameter at the top:

```
<xsl:param name="movieID"/>
```

I get a blank page with no information displayed at all.

I am able to get it to work by using the following ColdFusion code (movie_details.cfm)

```
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("movies.xml")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xmlInput"  file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset MyXslFile = Expandpath("movie_details.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput"  file="#MyXslFile#">

<cfset xslParam = StructNew() >
<cfset xslParam["movieID"] = "#url.movieID#" >

<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput, xslParam )>
<!--- data is output --->
<cfcontent type="text/html" reset="yes">
<cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```

However, I want to do the same with PHP.

Comment: Could it be that your $params argument is invalid, and so `transformToXML()` is failing? 'If you retrieve "false" from the transformToXML method, use libxml_get_last_error() or libxml_get_errors() to retrieve the errors.' (http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php)

Comment: I get the following warning on my movie_details.php page: "Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given"

Comment: Alex, I believe that warning is key to the problem. It's a very good idea to mention any warnings or errors present. See @Dave's answer.

Comment: @Alex: Show an example XML file, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues:

- Parameter name
- Passing parameters to transformer

## Parameter Name

Use `$movieID` (instead of `@movieID`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:param name="movieID" />

<xsl:template match="movie">
  <xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="$movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Passing Parameters

You will have to change your PHP code to call [setParameter](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php) because [transformToXML](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php) does not take additional parameters.

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('movies.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('movie_details.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$params = $_GET['movieID'];
$proc->setParameter('', 'movieID', $params );

echo $proc->transformToXML( $xml );
?>
```

Comment: +1: I think your suggestion about `setParameter()` is on-target. However I don't think the first XSLT stylesheet is receiving the movieID parameter from PHP; it's getting it from XML input, which the OP hasn't shown us.